# send toast text to a web server

Tags: android, server, toast

Hi everyone,

i want to send my toast shown text (user's current location) to my web server. Unfortunately, I really don't know about send data to server. and here is my toast activity code:

```
package com.example.aaaaaa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: search before ask any question

Answer (score 0):

you can send it via http request, volley library makes it very easy.
make sure you have the permission to use internet in your manifest

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.your-server.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + "?string=" + editText.getText().toString(),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```